# Count values for specific interval for each given timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

Say I've got the following `DataFrame`:

```
In [46]: timestamp = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/2/2018', freq='T')

In [47]: df = pd.DataFrame(timestamp, columns=['timestamp'])

In [48]: df['user'] = np.random.randint(10, size=len(timestamp))

In [49]: df['clicked'] = np.random.randint(2, size=len(timestamp))
```

Where each row represent whether a `user` has `clicked` in a given `timestamp`.

I'd like to add a new column, where the value for each row will be the number of times the user of the current row has `clicked` (i.e has value of `1`) in the past hour from the current row `timestamp`.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df = df.set_index('timestamp')
hour_count = df.groupby(['user'])['clicked'].rolling('1H').sum()
df =df.assign(rolling_sum=hour_count.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)).reset_index()
```

Comment: Why did you use `.assign()`? Also I would convert back to int: `df['rolling_sum'] = hour_count.reset_index(level=0, drop=True).astype(int)`

Comment: @jorijnsmit There is no difference. I just want to use a line code when I add `reset_index()` at the end.

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting `Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!` though, but I don't think I have duplicates by `user` and `timestamp`.

Comment: @galah92 This error shows that you have duplicates in your index. You can use `print(df[df.index.duplicated(keep='first')])` to look at duplicates. You can also use `df = df[~df.index.duplicated(keep='first')]` directly to delete duplicates.